# mysql index usage for query with OR

Tags: mysql, sql, select, indexing

I've got a query like this:

```
SELECT account.name, address.first_line 
FROM account
JOIN address ON address.id = account.address_id
WHERE
( account.date_updated >= '2016-05-05 12:00:00' 
OR
address.date_updated >= '2016-05-05 12:00:00' )
```

both the user table and the address table have an index on their respective 'date_updated' columns but when I do an explain neither of these indexes are being used.

Is there any way to change this? Or do I simply have to run two separate queries to get the information I want with the indexes being used.

I think this is different to this question: [MySQL: how to index an "OR" clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829544) because the fields on either side of the "OR" are from different tables and so you can't put a composite index on them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: how to index an "OR" clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829544/mysql-how-to-index-an-or-clause)

Answer (score 1):

It is hard for databases to optimize `OR`.  One method is to use `UNION` or `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT a.name, ad.first_line 
FROM account a JOIN
     address ad
     ON ad.id = a.address_id
WHERE a.date_updated >= '2016-05-05 12:00:00' 
UNION ALL
SELECT a.name, ad.first_line 
FROM account a JOIN
     address ad
     ON ad.id = a.address_id
WHERE ad.date_updated >= '2016-05-05 12:00:00' AND
      a.date_updated < '2016-05-05 12:00:00'
```

You can write this query using `UNION` rather than `UNION ALL` and leave out the `NOT EXISTS` clause.  However, the duplicate elimination in `UNION` is often slower than just removing the possible duplicates using the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not use indexes for `WHERE` clauses that have `OR` in them. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829544/mysql-how-to-index-an-or-clause) has more information. MySQL [WHERE clause documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimizations.html).

I would try to union the two together like

```
SELECT account.name, address.first_line FROM account 
JOIN address ON address.id = account.address_id 
WHERE account.date_updated >= '2016-05-05 12:00:00'

UNION

SELECT account.name, address.first_line FROM account 
JOIN address ON address.id = account.address_id 
WHERE address.date_updated >= '2016-05-05 12:00:00'
```

Comment: Gordon's answer is slightly better than this one; he explains why.